# How does a patients distribution affect a trials distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, random-variable, clinical-trials

For example, the trial has a normal distribution with mean 10 and stdev 35. However, that distribution is calculated using the average of each patients measurements.
Say each patient in the trial has an internal normal distribution with mean 17 and stdev 21, which means their measurements have this distribution.

The questions is: what percent of the patients in the trial will be at 15 or above? If it is just the original distribution using the average of each patient, it is pretty easy to calculate using a simple z-score. However, what if we don't use an average for each patient and only test them once and use that measurement? What percentage of the patients in the trial will be at 15 or above then?

I'm not too sure how to approach this question and what portions of it are significant. Currently I am thinking that is a linear combination of random variables and I can use the tower property. If X ~ Normal(10, 35) is the original trial using averages, can I say that if we only test each patient once the patient's internal distribution is modelling a parameter of the trial distribution? If that is the case then X ~ Normal(10, y) and y ~ Normal(17, 21) and then I can use the tower property to find the new Variance(X) and then I can just calculate a z-score to answer the question of what percentage of patients will be >= 15 if they are just measured once?

I was also thinking whether using a patient average vs single measurement even matters. Like does the patient distribution even affect anything? Does measuring once just change the trial distribution and we just have a new mean and stdev to calculate a simple z-score with?

Comment: How does the trial have a distribution with mean 10 if each patient has a distribution with mean 17?

Comment: So I'm not exactly sure how the numbers were obtained, but from what I gather the trial is using the averages of several hundred patients. Then there was a thought experiment where they took around 20 patients and used their data and averaged the mean and stdev of all of those 20 patients. Then they just assumed the mean and stdev they got from the 20 patients was representative of the entire population and asked what would happen if they got new patients and only measured them once, what would happen?

Comment: Although now that you asked this question, now I'm starting to think that the question doesn't make sense. These 20 patients that they used to get the new mean and stdev is just a smaller version of the original trial distribution, it's not a combination of random variables right?

Comment: So the question of the proportion of patients with >= 15 even if they are only measured once is still just a z-score using mean 10 and stdev 35 since those are the population parameters right? It doesn't really matter whether you measure them once or average multiple times. And the patient distribution they got from the 20 patient sample is irrelevant right?